# What did happen at the beginning of 21st century that usage of inverted signs suddenly surged?

Tags: historia

I was looking for the past usage of some of the inverted signs in books.

I found out that all of them suddenly surged after 2004-2005.

[Google Ngram Viewer 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%A1&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C2%A1%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C2%A1%3B%2Cc0), [Google Ngram Viewer 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%BF&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C2%BF%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C2%BF%3B%2Cc0), [Google Ngram Viewer 3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%BF%C2%A1&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C2%BF%20%C2%A1%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C2%BF%20%C2%A1%3B%2Cc0), [Google Ngram Viewer 4](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C2%A1%C2%BF&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=32&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C2%A1%20%C2%BF%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C2%A1%20%C2%BF%3B%2Cc0)

What is the reason for the surge in using these signs after 2004-2005?

Comment: I suspect that since they all increase at the same time and with a similar profile that this is a change in the algorithm being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's related with the growing use of spanish in Internet.

These symbols are used in spanish language, which today is the 3° idiom in Internet. So, his presence is more and more visible.

Comment: I think the NGrams are for books so your explanation seems rather far from the mark. Can you edit it to explain the link between the internet and books?